# ingres 10s sql row number

Tags: sql, ingres

I have two simple one column tables like this:

Table one:

```
from_date
01.01.18
15.01.18
23.01.18
01.02.18
```

Table two:

```
to_date
15.01.18
23.01.18
01.02.18
05.02.18
```

All I want to do is join them on `a.row_number = b.row_number`

I can't find a way within Ingres SQL to do this.  The best idea I have is to add a row number column to each table and join on this.  I have come across the CREATE SEQUENCE function, but I can't find clear instructions on how to apply it

Comment: The row_number function is working - I'll investigate that....

Answer (score 1):

[According to the manual](http://docs.actian.com/ingres/11.0/index.html#page/SQLRef%2FAnalytical_Functions.htm%23) Ingres supports window functions and `row_number()`, so you should be able to do:

```
select coalese(a.rn, b.rn) as rn, a.from_date, b.to_date
from (
   select from_date, row_number() over (order by from_date) as rn
   from table_a
) a 
  full join (
    select to_date, row_number() over (order by to_date) as rn
    from table_b
  ) b on a.rn = b.rn;
```

The full (outer) join ensures that rows from both tables are returned even if one tables has fewer rows than the other. If you are 100% sure that both tables always contain the same number of rows, you can use an inner join instead (remove the `full` keyword)

I don't have Ingres to test this, so although the above is ANSI standard SQL, there might be things that Ingres does not support

Simpler without full outer join and `coalesce()`:

```
select a.rn, a.from_date, b.to_date
from (
   select from_date, row_number() over (order by from_date) as rn
   from table_a
) a 
  join (
    select to_date, row_number() over (order by to_date) as rn
    from table_b
  ) b on a.rn = b.rn;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately the Ingres I am using does not recognise those functions (Ingres 10S)

Answer (score 0):

with temp1 as (

select row_number() over (order by from_date) as row from tableA

),

temp2 as (

select row_number() over (order by from_date) as row from tableB

)

select a.*,b.*

from temp1 a

join temp2 b on a.row=b.row

Comment: But you claimed that Ingres 10s does not support window functions.

Comment: It did not recognise the coalese function you started with - and I assumed in error it wouldn't recognise the others. Apologies!

Comment: "coalese" is a typo; coalesce() is available in Ingres 10.1 (10S).

Comment: ah, please could you repost your original answer - I'd be interested to see it again